# Connect Error (2003)Can't connect to MySQL server on 10061

Tags: php, mysql, server

I want to connect my localhost to remote server mysql5.domain.com

```
Connect Error (2003)Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql5.domain.de' (10061)

define('HOST', "mysql5.domain.de");

define('DB', "x");

define('USER', "y");

define('PASSWORD', "pw");
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried http://mysql5.domain.de and https://mysql5.domain.com.

Comment: is there a mysql server running in mysql5.domain.de?

Comment: Yes, there is a mysql server running on.

Comment: Don't share your password with the whole world! Also, please show us how you tried to connect to MySQL, here we can see only the values to be used.

Comment: If you're sure there is an mysql server on that domain, and the port is open to yours, try connect to it in command line; if it failed, it means the server is down

Comment: @Alex.Fu it might also mean that there is no privilege.

Comment: Needed to create ssh tunnel because domainfactory has an exta tool https://www.df.eu/de/support/df-faq/webhosting/webspace-zugriff/ssh/#acc5877

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, sure it may be that, thanks for reminding.